# Date to Integer YYYMMDD in Standar SQL (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to convert a date to an integer with the format YYYMMDD in Bigquery.

I tried with:

`PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', response_date)`

but its not working (Error: No matching signature for function PARSE_DATE for argument types: STRING, DATE. Supported signature: PARSE_DATE(STRING, STRING) at [1:8])

response_date: Date Format

Wanted Result: 20210201 as an integer or string

If anyone know the correct sintax it would be really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One method is arithmetic:

```
select extract(year from response_date) * 10000 + extract(month from response_date) * 100 + extract(day from response_date)
```

Another method is `FORMAT_DATE()`:

```
select cast(format_date('%Y%m%d', response_date) as int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (*might look funny/silly but works*)

```
select  translate('' || response_date, '-', '')
```

and then you can do with resulted string whatever cast'ing you need or just leave as is (as string)

... can easily be tested with below query

```
select  translate('' || current_date(), '-', '')
```

with output

[image]

But obviously - the best way to go is with FORMAT_DATE() as in Gordon's answer :o)